# Could a city's groundwater be isolated and manipulated?

Tags: technology, technological-development, macroengineering, utopia

On Earth, many cities and regions experience periods of drought, despite the fact that so much of of Earth's surface is covered with water.

With underground engineering and enough energy and infrastructure, could the groundwater of some given region (say, a city or municipality) be purified and relocated to more useful regions?

What would be the ramifications of such a feat, eg. on local ecologies?

Comment: Doesn't that happen already? Water is isolated, purified, chlorinated and in many cases fluoridated, all for the utopic purpose of increasing general health. The ramifications of fluoridation are still being debated. Can you tell us a bit more what you have in mind, narrow the scope a bit?

Comment: Hi DJG, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. I try not to vote to close newcomer's questions, so please note that (a) asking more than one question is grounds for closure (Needs Focus), (b) asking for unspecified and unlimited ramifications fails the [help/on-topic]'s book test for too broad (VTC:  Not About Worldbuilding According to the Help Center) and fails the basic premise that a Q should be specific and answerable, which is another close reason (Needs Details). Please ask only one question (no compound questions!) and explain your conditions and limitations... (\*continued\*)

Comment: ...(e.g., what is "macroscale underground engineering?" what are the purposes? What are your goals or reasons for asking the question? What is it your own research can't explain? etc.) Please take the time to take our [tour] and read the following two Help Center pages ([1] [help/on-topic], [2] [help/dont-ask]) so you better understand how this site works. Thanks.

Comment: You need to look at the terms you're using here; **water table** has a very specific technical meaning it is "the depth of total pore saturation of the substrate". It is an, often theoretical, depth below the surface from which point all the pore spaces in the soil/stone are completely full of water, except under [rare circumstances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_table#Perched_water_tables) everything below that point is saturated, everything, all the way down.

Comment: Is the question can it be done (the answer is yes) or is the question what the effects might be? // take a look at the effects on Venice of pumping out groundwater from below it // you need to define (or delete from the question?) your utopic aims, what they're trying to achieve by adding or extracting groundwater & how they're doing it or no one can really answer the question (& you may find your answer doing that).

Comment: Define "utopic purposes".  For one example, the water table in California's Central Valley is regularly pumped for irrigation, to the extent that the ground has subsided as much as 28 ft/9 m in places: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Valley_land_subsidence  If you're a farmer there, you might consider this manipulation "utopic".  Others might disagree.

Comment: this really depends on the municipality and what you want to do to it. some have multiple water sources.

Comment: You're  close to getting my reopen vote and an answer but you're still asking two questions, the first is a relatively simple yes/no, a good answer will have details of how. The latter is a huge beast about ecology that can be answered but maybe not within the scope of the Worldbuilding Stack because it verges on the "book answer" but you could maybe look at some specifics.

Comment: I too would like to reopen. I appreciate your recent edits, but I'm still at a loss as to what kind of *fictional problem or issue* your world or scenario is facing that can't be answered with the usual armamentatium of water handling solutions we already use. And their ramifications.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. We do it already.

The case I know about is Christchurch, New Zealand.
When originally settled, it was a swamp. They dug out some rivers to lower the water table to drain the swamp. Under the city, lots of water sits in aquifers (water-saturated dirt/gravel). This is the town water supply and is actively managed by lots of factors. Some of those factors include:

- Where they draw the water from. There are lots of pumps, and they chose where to take it from based on availability and salinity (salt water incursion from the sea is a problem in coastal areas)
- Upstream agriculture. Strong controls of upstream irrigation limits ensure adequate water reaches the city. Leechate limits ensure the water remains pure enough to drink.

What are the ramifications? That the town has a good water supply!

Comment: I like how the answer contains example and ramification - once again, case of reality bigger than fantasy, lol, 10/10